# Explaination RPC (remote procedure call) and RMI (remote method invocation)

Tags: rmi, rpc

Can someone explain this in a (better/simpler) way?

The remote procedure call (RPC) approach extends the common programming
abstraction of the procedure call to distributed environments, allowing a calling process to call a procedure in a remote node as if it is local.

Remote method invocation (RMI) is similar to RPC but for distributed objects, with added benefits in terms of using object-oriented programming concepts in
distributed systems and also extending the concept of an object reference to the
global distributed environments, and allowing the use of object references as
parameters in remote invocations.

I just don't understand the way it is explained...

Comment: Its all about structural vs oop programming.

Answer (score 1):

Taking out the remote aspect, which is common to both, the difference is the difference between calling  a function in a procedural language and calling a method in an OOP language.